# Почему lottie выдает ошибку ImportError: cannot import name 'PngRenderer' from 'lottie.exporters.cairo'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, gif

Пытаюсь конвертировать .tgs стикер в gif, используй lottie:

```
from lottie.exporters.gif import export_gif
from lottie.parsers.tgs import parse_tgs
import logging
def convert_tgs_to_gif(tgs_file, gif_file):

    try:
        animation = parse_tgs(tgs_file)


        export_gif(animation, gif_file, skip_frames=5, dpi=48)
        return True
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("Error occurred while converting TGS to GIF.")
        return False
```

выдает следующую ошибку:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PngRenderer' from 'lottie.exporters.cairo'
```

Пробовал импортировать библиотеку целиком, импортировать PngRenderer, ничего не помогло
`(Поставил тег json потому что .tgs, по той информации что я загуглил это просто json, но как то хитро сжатый)`

Comment: Как ставили библиотеку `lottie`?

Comment: Да, конечно ставил

Comment: @mironovmeow pip install lottie[all]

Comment: Хм... А если `pip install glaxnimate`?

Comment: Давно пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Хорошо... Я сейчас попробую проверить версию на pypi, возможно она отличается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142865/discussion-between-mironovmeow-and-bubunduc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался в этом сложном вопросе. В данной библиотеке ещё не настроенно адекватное отображение ошибок. Здесь проблема в совершенно другой библиотеке. Для работы [`PngRenderer`](https://gitlab.com/mattbas/python-lottie/-/blob/master/lib/lottie/exporters/cairo.py#L40) требуется библиотека `cairosvg`. А для нормальной работы на windows ему [требуется libcairo-2.dll](https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows). Следовательно, **решение данной проблемы: правильная установка `cairosvg`**.

Ответ с [английского](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913080/17349246) StackOverflow по установке `cairosvg`